# how to take variable from remote host to local host in bash

Tags: bash

```
a=5
ssh abc@ip << EOF
b=7
echo "Remote Host b is $b " 
EOF
echo "Local host b is $b "
```

Taking value of a local variable from remote host to localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
r=$(ssh abc@ip 'b=7; echo $b')
echo "Remote Host b is $r"
```

or

```
ssh abc@ip 'b=7; echo "Remote Host b is $b"'
```